# Changing S3 folder with 1.8 million from private to public-read fails without detailed error

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a public S3 bucket that I uploaded a folder of tiled images (for a gigapixel image). The upload was originally via the commandline aws-cli tools, but the folder was not set to have public-read (it was all private). The folder contains about 1.8 million tile files (jpg images).
The steps I took:

- Log into the console
- Select the folder in the bucket that I want to make public
- Select Actions > Make Public

The process of making all the objects under the folder commences with a progress-bar, but then fails after a couple of percent. There's no indication of the error.
See the screenshot of when this fails [image]

Trying to set the bucket permissions with s3cmd or aws-cli works, but this seems to be a much slower process.

I can't tell if I'm doing something wrong here. The same steps work with a much smaller folder (I copied one of the subfolders for testing, and the make-public function worked just fine). It *seems* like there's some bug in the console, but I want to see if anyone else has had a similar issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to set permissions on multiple objects, or a folder of objects, do not set the permissions on the objects themselves.

Instead, use an Amazon S3 **bucket policy**, which can instantly grant access to a whole bucket, or specific paths within a bucket.

See: [Bucket Policy Examples - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-bucket-policies.html)

Here is an example to make a folder public:

```
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal": "*",
      "Action":["s3:GetObject"],
      "Resource":["arn:aws:s3:::BUCKETNAME/tiles/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```